Pass json file contents from a directory in ADLS to stored procedure
I have a directory in ADLS which has 100 json files. I want list all the json files and pass the JSON data from each file to a stored procedure using adf. How can I do it? I will parse the content of the json file in Stored Procedure and insert them to an SQL table.
I am able to do a lookup activity where I am providing the directory which contains all the json files and selecting wild card filepath and providing the stored procedure with i/p as @string(activity('Lookup1').output. I am able to process all the files. But its in a single occurence where all the files are processed. How can I process the files one by one i.e rather than the stored procedure getting once for all the files, it should get executed multiple times i.e. once for each file

Whether all json files have same structure?

Why do you want to use stored procedure? We can use copy activity itself in ADF to do this. Is there any req. to use SP? Could you explain the requirement

It becomes easier to play with stored procedure later. The json has objects as well as arrays which will go to different tables

Yes all have same structure

You can use combination of Get meta data activity and for-each activity to achieve your requirement.
Create two JSON datasets, give the path till the folder in one dataset and use it in the Get meta data activity. Use the Childitems property in this activity.

Next, take a for-each activity and give the childitems array @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems from Get meta data to the for-each. As you want to execute the file one by one, Check the sequential checkmark in this.

Inside for-each, take a lookup activity and give the second JSON dataset to this. In the second dataset, create a string parameter filename and use it in the filepath of the dataset @dataset().filename like below.

In the lookup, give the @item().name from the for-each to this parameter.

In each iteration, the lookup will give the JSON data of every file like below.

Inside ForEach after lookup activity, you can use Stored procedure activity or Script activity to call your stored procedure. You can use the expression @string(activity('Lookup1').output.value) or @string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]) as per the lookup output JSON to pass it to your stored procedure.

Great, it worked for you : ).
